# check if directory or file exist or not on ftp server and put it if does not exist

Tags: shell, ftp, sh

I am writing a shell script to check specified directory or file exist on FTP server. I want to check lib directory and web.config file already exist or not on FTP server, if file or directory does not exist then create a directory and put the file on the specified location(site/wwwroot). I have written a snippet of code.

```
ftp -ipn $ftphost <<EOF
user $username $pswd
binary
cd site/wwwroot
ls web.config
cd lib
quit
EOF

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then 
  echo "Files Exist";
  ftp -ipn $ftphost <<EOF
  user $username $pswd
  binary
  cd site/wwwroot
  del web.config
  cd lib
  mdel *
  cd ..
  rmdir lib
  mkdir lib
  mput web.config
  quit
EOF
else
  echo "The Files does not Exists";
  ftp -ipn $ftphost <<EOF
  user $username $pswd
  binary
  cd site/wwwroot
  mkdir lib
  mput web.config
  quit
EOF
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample shell script to check if file or directory exists,replace file and direcoty path with actual path.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="web.config"
directory="lib"

# check if file exist, if not then create
if [ -f $file ];then echo "File exist"; else echo "File does not exist" && touch /path/$file;fi

# check if directoy exist, if not then create
if [ -d $directory ];then echo "File exist"; else echo "directory does not exist" && mkdir -p /path/$directory;fi
```

Comment: I have to check specified file/directory exist over the FTP and perform the operation based on it. Case 1: If files/directory already exist then clean up and upload fresh files.Case 2: If files don't exist then upload files and create a directory without cleanup.